# php shell_Exec not working while the command works in shell

Tags: php, imagemagick, shell-exec

I have to use `imagemagick` `convert` command from php. So I'm using `shell_exec` but the output of that is null string. I know that the command convert doesn't print anyting on STDOUT but the desired output of `convert` is also not achieved. also `exec` doesn't work. these commands run fine from shell or from php command line. What can be the issue?

***EDIT*** :adding the 2>&1, I learn that convert is throwing an error : `missing an image filename`/a5d98168a524a331c5e06d60096debd63cbdce1f.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2970.`where the full command is`convert /var/www/weblog/web/uploads/poster/a5d98168a524a331c5e06d60096debd63cbdce1f.png /var/www/weblog/web/uploads/poster/a5d98168a524a331c5e06d60096debd63cbdce1f.jpg`.

Comment: Look into the `error.log` or add `2>&1` after the command.

Comment: check app has write permission on the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that Apache is using in linux is called www-data, you have to make sure that that user has permission to work with the files and commands you use. You can either use chmod to change the file permissions or chown to change the file/dir owners to www-data.