# ffmpeg MAMP "dyld: Library not loaded" error

Tags: php, macos, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg on Mac OSX 10.7.3 in MAMP through PHP's `exec()` command, I have an absolute path set to call ffmpeg, e.g.

```
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "/sample.avi"
```

But I receive the following error -

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libopenjpeg.1.dylib  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopenjpeg.1.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libJPEG.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

N.B. ffmpeg was installed through Macports.

It works from the command line.

What to do?

**EDIT**

I've reopened this - originally thought `shell_exec()` solved the issue, but infact it should be called differently - and I didn't realise until investigating further today. Here is my code using shell_exec and still giving the error above:

```
 $cmd = '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -h';
 $cmd = escapeshellcmd($cmd) . ' 2>&1';
 $output = shell_exec($cmd);
 var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Possibly an issue because ffmpeg was installed through macports and not in the MAMP environment?

Comment: I added this as an answer now, removing the other comments.

Comment: My bad: `shell_exec` was returning `null` - I didn't notice until investigating further today. When I call `shell_exec` correctly I get the same error.

Comment: [relevant?](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20060321125056713)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in MAMP and I've installed ffmpeg via macports.

This might not be the best fix but it has me up and running for now:

In the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` file and comment the following lines as below:

```
#DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and restart Apache

Comment: Thanks. I had trouble getting ImageMagic to work via macports and mamp. This worked for me and I also had to add the following line to my php script
putenv("PATH=" . $_ENV["PATH"] . ":/opt/local/bin");

Comment: I've long since moved everything to macports. It was a pain initially getting everything up and running but worth it to prevent these niggles in the long run!

Answer (score 2):

Commenting out the line `#DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"` will work in the short term but it could break other things, since you're removing the line that MAMP uses to tell the server where it keeps its libraries.

A better solution would be to change the line to this:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

so that you're just prepending `/usr/local/lib:` to the already-given path. This tells Apache to look in `/usr/local/lib` first, and then if that doesn't work, to look in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib`.

So if you install something via, say, Brew and there are two versions, it'll look in the one you installed with Brew first, before it uses whatever came with MAMP, which is more likely to be out of date. But if it's something that only came with MAMP, that you didn't install separately or that is MAMP-specific, you won't break it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure PHP's `exec` is using the same shell as you, when you use the commandline.

Probably [`shell_exec`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/shell_exec) helps.

See as well [php shell_Exec not working while the command works in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808413/php-shell-exec-not-working-while-the-command-works-in-shell).

Comment: Thanks accepted - otherwise what are the main differences between `exec` and `shell_exec` that would mean shell_exec works but not exec?

Comment: @benedict_w: I have to admit, I have no clue. I just remembered this did help some time and it was argued that way. http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/exec.c#53 ; http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/exec.c#434 - both are using `VCWD_POPEN`

Comment: Looks like this might not be the correct answer - while `exec` gives me the error above `shell_exec` is returning null. Reopening until solved. :(

Comment: I fixed a separate issue with the `shell_exec` command and it's now giving me the same error as above.

Comment: check the user, e.g. do some `shellexec('whoami')`.

Comment: This gives 'benedict' i.e. the account I am running MacOsx under. It seems to be the environment variables that are different... Anyway I have a fix that has this up and running for now (posted) - I hope to move from MAMP once I have a stable environment setup anyway. Many thanks for your assistance!