# exec() command on mac osx returns 5

Tags: macos, command, exec

I am trying to execute a thumbnail converter script phantomjs. 
From my terminal it works fine but in my web page returns 5 code. Is that a problem with the permissions?  I am using php 5.3 + MAMP

```
            $output = array();
            $command = "./bundles/MainBundle/js/phantomjs /bundles/MainBundle/js/convert.js";
            $return_var=0;
            exec($command,$output,$return_var);
```

HELP! please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by unsetting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable which appears to be set by MAMP but will confuse PhantomJS.

```
$command = "unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ; ./bundles/MainBundle/js/phantomjs";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method:

In the /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars file and comment the following lines as below:

```
#DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and restart Apache.

*Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125539/291573*