# phantomjs on Mac OS X works from the command line, not via exec()

Tags: php, phantomjs

the following works fine on the command line for user xyz:

```
/opt/local/bin/phantomjs --version
1.9.1
```

But, in PHP, with the same user (xyz), I get an error code 5

```
exec('/opt/local/bin/phantomjs --version', $o, $r)
echo $r
```

I'm using MAMP, and exec() normally works fine.
If anyone knows how to debug this I would e very greatful!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Amal Murali for pointing me in the right direction!

This is documented also in [exec() command on mac osx returns 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314564), and can be fixed by unsetting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

The following command will work:

```
exec('unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ; /opt/local/bin/phantomjs --version', $o, $r)
echo $r
```

Cheers,

Albert.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output by appending `2>&1` at the end of your command, like so:

```
exec('/opt/local/bin/phantomjs --version 2>&1', $o, $r);
var_dump($r);
```

The `2>&1` says to send standard error to where ever standard output is being redirected as well.  See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line) answer for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The error code is now 133 and the output is: dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem with the environment variables. A common issue with macports is using the 'stock' apachectl that comes with OSX (located at /usr/sbin/apachectl) instead of the macports apachectl located at /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl.

In most cases, the stock version will appear to work correctly. However, only the macports version will establish the correct environment (i.e,. using /opt/local/apache2/bin/envvars, and setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH correctly.

If you run `sudo apachectl` to control apache, you are likely running the stock version of apachectl.

You may want to delete it (or rename it to /usr/sbin/apachectl.orig) and symlink instead to the macports version:

```
mv /usr/bin/apachectlapachectl /usr/bin/apachectlapachectl.orig
ln /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl /usr/bin/apachectl
```

If you are still having issues then you may need to delve deepet into the environment variables being used by apache (and thus passed to php).